# Как убрать лишний "border-right" между пунктами меню ?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/5qC5H/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xY7GQ/

Comment: @soledar10, почему-то привидение сдвигаются буквы ?

Comment: уже исправил 
http://jsfiddle.net/xY7GQ/